# Placing column values in variables using single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL server, how can I place the value of more than one column in variables using one query?

Ex: my query is:

```
SELECT ET.ID,ET.Description,ET.DefaultTemplateText 
FROM TBL_EMAILTEMPLATE ET 
WHERE ET.NAME='OneWeekReminder'
```

I want to place the column values in variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
Declare @id INT
Declare @desc VarChar(100)
Declare @template VarChar(100)

SELECT @id = ET.ID, @desc = ET.Description, @template = ET.DefaultTemplateText 
FROM TBL_EMAILTEMPLATE ET 
WHERE ET.NAME='OneWeekReminder'
```

Comment: If the query returns multiple rows, it would just set the values multiple times

Answer (score 6):

declare the variables first then set them in the select clause.

```
declare
    @ID int,
    @Description varchar(10),
    @DefaultTemplateText varchar(10)

select
    @ID = ET.ID,
    @Description = ET.Description,
    @DefaultTemplateText = ET.DefaultTemplateText
from
    TBL_EMAILTEMPLATE ET
where
    ET.NAME = 'OneWeekReminder'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can separate multiple assignments with a comma.  For example:

```
declare @a varchar(50)
declare @b varchar(50)

select 
    @a = et.Description
,   @b = et.DefaultTemplateText
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming only one row,

```
SELECT @id = ET.ID, @Description = ET.Description, @DefaultTemplateText = ET.DefaultTemplateText
FROM TBL_EMAILTEMPLATE ET 
WHERE ET.NAME='OneWeekReminder'
```